# How to copy only selected word in Notepad++

Tags: notepad++

I have some codes like you can see below so i wanted to copy specific lines that contain "TH" word in lines!So how can i do in notepad++ or suggest any other way if presented!

```
admin|admin|TH|873|
root|root|KR|405|
support|support|KR|468|
user|user|KR|421|
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the bookmark feature of Notepad++ like this:

1. double click word
2. use Search -> Mark... (the selected word should be in the search field
3. check Bookmark line, (check Purge for each search or click clear all marks if necessary)
4. click Mark all
5. click Search -> Bookmark -> Copy Bookmarked lines
6. paste the lines